# Posting spreadsheet table in Wordpress page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, templates

I'm trying to embed a Google worksheet in a page in my Wordpress website. 
Exporting from Google gives me two files, one html an one sheet.css. The html links to the CSS file via `href="resources/sheet.css"`. I have created a resources directory in my theme folder and placed the CSS inside, however, when I post the html in a page, the two files don't seem to be linked and the table is out of style (the cells are huge). 
Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: have you any example?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know for sure without seeing your html code, but it seems like the url doesn't point to the correct location.

Entering the complete path of the file should solve the problem, if the rest of the link tag is correctly entered.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I tried what you suggested but it didn't work This is the page after I posted the html: http://www.diktioagiasparaskevis.gr/diatheseis/order/ The table does not inherit content style. The html im posting contains following script which puzzles me:

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zwe7K1np Do I need this / can I post this in a page?

Comment: The script seems to be responsible for the positioning, but it is difficult to say without all the code.

Why did you decide to export the files from google? If you want to embed a file from Google Docs, then you can just follow [this](https://en.support.wordpress.com/google-docs/).

Comment: I know you can do it like this. My ultimate goal is to create a form out of this spreadsheet that posts entries to an other file. But i need to figure out the exported files first.

Comment: I see. Have you tried to see, what it looks like without the link tag for the CSS. So, without using CSS at all?
Maybe the link of the html and CSS works, but the CSS is wonky.